# How to remove a trailing blank line in docx4j?

Tags: java, docx4j

I am trying to replace placeholders in the word document. The code that I wrote replaces the text, but the problem is that it creates an empty space if an empty string is passed. Is there a way to remove that empty space and the trailing blank line if an empty string is passed ?

The piece of code I wrote is like this:

```
private void replaceText(Tr row,  String name, String placeholder) {
  List<Object> texts = getAllElementFromObject(row, Text.class);      
  for (Object text : texts) {  
      Text textElement = (Text) text;  
      if (textElement.getValue().contains(placeholder)) {  
        String temp = textElement.getValue();
        temp = temp.replace(placeholder, name);
        textElement.setValue(temp);  
        return;
      }  
    }  
  }
```

This replaces the text, but leaves a trailing a blank new line if the "temp" is empty string.

What I am getting now in the docx file if "TextToBeReplaced2" is :

```
TextToBeReplaced1          
TextToBeReplaced2    
TextToBeReplaced3
```

After replacing it becomes like this:

```
FirstName    


LastName
```

What I want to get is :

```
FirstName       
LastName
```

with no space in between if TextToBeReplaced2 is empty string.

I hope I could explain my problem. If required I can also share screenshots.

Comment: Best to look at the XML; use that to describe what you want versus what you are getting.  An alternative way of approaching this sort of problem is to use a conditional content control (ie to remove the content control if some part of its content is blank)

Comment: @JasonPlutext I edited the question now. Hope I could explain my problem more clearly. One of the other way to fix it can be to add new lines, if we replace all the textTobereplaced variables with only one. And then add new lines as per required. But I could not do that as well, as the new lines don't get printed on the docx.